# JavaScript cut string with space

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have this String Var str:

```
3002033185160426195531991010-00000000050086093500001       ул. Щевченко 36 а/б           0056763185160426195517991010-00000000080086093500001       ул. Щевченко 36 а/б           0056753185160426195501991010-00000000090086093500001       ул. Щевченко 36 а/б           005674
```

I need cut string and create new array with values:

```
array[0] : "3002033185160426195531991010-00000000050086093500001"
array[1] : "0056763185160426195517991010-00000000080086093500001"
array[2] : "0056753185160426195501991010-00000000090086093500001"
```

I tried to use `str.split(" ");` but there will be a very large array. How to do it? Help me please!!!

Answer (score 1):

This works but its a specific fix for your particular string:

```
s.split(' ').filter(function(a) {
  return a.length > 8;
})
```

[Working example](https://jsbin.com/wuguco/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that format is fixed:

```
> arr = str.match(/\d{28}-\d{23}/g)
> ["3002033185160426195531991010-00000000050086093500001", "0056763185160426195517991010-00000000080086093500001", "0056753185160426195501991010-00000000090086093500001"]
```

Answer (score 1):

try a string library like [stringjs](http://stringjs.com/) for example.
you can use the collapseWhitespace() method to achieve something like this:

```
var str = S('  String   \t libraries are   \n\n\t fun\n!  ').collapseWhitespace().s; //'String libraries are fun !'
```

then you can split using the .split(' ') method.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.match(/[\d-]{50,}/g)
// => ["3002033185160426195531991010-00000000050086093500001", "0056763185160426195517991010-00000000080086093500001", "0056753185160426195501991010-00000000090086093500001"]
```

You can tweak the number `50` which should differentiate big numbers you want, like `"3002033185160426195531991010-00000000050086093500001"`, from small numbers you don't, like `"36"`.

Answer (score 1):

### Working example

```js
var str = '3002033185160426195531991010-00000000050086093500001       ул. Щевченко 36 а/б           0056763185160426195517991010-00000000080086093500001       ул. Щевченко 36 а/б           0056753185160426195501991010-00000000090086093500001       ул. Щевченко 36 а/б           005674';
var results = str.match(/[\d-]{50,}/g);
for (i in results) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI"); 
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(results[i].toString().trim()); 
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  
  document.getElementById("results").appendChild(node);

}
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>
```